# Como salvar o caminho de uma imagem no Banco de Dados?

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, imagem, servlet, path

Estou utilizando JDBC e pegando uma imagem para guardar no banco de dados. Porém eu quero guardar a imagem no HD e salvar no banco apenas o caminho (`path`) dela.

Eu queria saber qual é o melhor tipo que eu uso para manipular e salvar a imagem (`Image` ou `File`). Já que a maioria das funções do `File` são relativas à `String`;

A imagem é selecionada pelo `form` do `html` e passada como se fosse um `servlet`, porem, eu a uso numa de Controller para que fique um código mais simples e coeso.

Comment: Se for inserir apenas o caminho, porque não uma String ? File.getAbsolutePath() ?

Comment: A imagem é selecionada pelo form do html. Como se fosse um servlet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Salvando o caminho completo

Para salvar em um banco de dados você deve salvar o caminho como uma `String`.

Obviamente o seu código que lê e grava os registros pode encapsular essa String em um `File`  por exemplo, recuperando a `String` banco e criando um `File` ou recuperando o caminho do arquivo como `String` e gravando no banco de dados.

Nessa situação, faça o que for mais conveniente.

## Organizando os arquivos

Porém, a não ser que seja um requisito absolutamente necessário do seu sistema, eu não salvaria o caminho completo dos arquivos.

Em geral, seria mais adequado definir um diretório na configuração do programa e salvar todos os arquivos selecionados naquele diretório.

Então você pode salvar apenas os nomes das imagens no banco e, quando precisar salvar o arquivo, basta fazer algo como:

```
new File(configuracao.getPastaArquivos(), nomeArquivo)
```

Aliás, nem o nome do arquivo é necessário. Se você tiver, por exemplo, uma tabela no banco de dados onde salva as informações do arquivo, pode simplesmente salvar o arquivo na pasta usando o ID como nome.

Então o caminho no disco seria algo assim:

```
new File(configuracao.getPastaArquivos(), arquivo.getId())
```

Dessa forma, os dados do arquivo (como o seu nome) ficam no banco de dados e você tem tudo organizado em uma pasta pelo ID.

É mais fácil fazer backup, mover os arquivos para outro local se necessário e também evita problemas com caracteres especiais nos nomes, espaços e acentuação. Também permite situações onde dois usuários do sistema enviam um arquivo com mesmo nome.

Answer (score 3):

**Não é possível** por questões de segurança.

De forma bem simples: Nenhum site precisa saber qualquer coisa sobre sistema de arquivos do usuário. Quando um arquivo é enviado para um servidor somente os dados do mesmo são importantes.

No Firefox você ainda consegue visualizar o `mozFullPath` que mostra o *absolute path* de um arquivo utilizando Javascript, mas se tentar pegar/usar esse valor ele retornará uma string vazia.

```js
/* CTRL+SHIFT+J para ver a mensagem no console. */

document.getElementById('file').onchange = function(){
    console.dir(this.files[0]);
    console.log("mozFullPath: " + this.files[0]['mozFullPath']); // vai retornar ""
};
```

```html
<input id='file' type='file'/>
```

Você verá algo assim:

[image: mozfullpath]

Comment: Entendi. Mas eu quero é primeiro salvar o arquivo no meu HD. Para depois pegar o Caminho, e assim guarda o caminho no banco de dados.O meu problema maior e saber qual tipo de variavel eu uso para manipular a imagem. Porque se eu uso o `Image` eu não consigo salva-lo no sistema, e se eu uso o tipo `File` eu não consigo coloca a imagem dentro do tipo File.